# 2nd Order Optimal Control Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, control-theory

I'm working on a homework problem in optimal controls and my plant model is described as:
$$\ddot{x}(t) = u(t)$$
The performance index (cost function) is described by:
$$J = 1/2\int_0^5u^{2}(t)dt\,$$
And the boundary conditions are
$$x(0) = 0,$$
$$x(5)=0,$$
$$\dot{x}(0)=2$$
$$\dot{x}(5)=0$$
I'm not sure how to start this problem when I need $\dot{x}(t)$ to start with. Do I just integrate the plant model?

Answer (score 2):

This was a stupid question where I had a brain-fart. What confused me was that description of the system, $\ddot{x}(t)=u(t)$, looked like the state equation.

The correct states for this system would be:
$$x_1(t) = x(t)$$
$$x_2(t) = \dot{x}(t) = \dot{x}_1(t)$$

After rewriting in this form, I would be able to proceed with solving for the optimal control solution using the state equation...
$$\dot{x}_1(t)=x_2(t)$$
$$\dot{x}_2(t)=u(t)$$